# Next JS Paging - Using same page file

Tags: next.js

In Next Js project I have a blog page. This loads at mywebsite.com/blog. I then have pagination in place which when navigating and want to use mywebsite.com/blog/page/2 etc for SEO reasons.

Current structure:

```
pages/
--- blog/index.js
--- blog/page/[page].js
```

Can I use / inherit index.js to use in [page].js rather than having the same file essentially twice? I need to getServerProps in both pages of course.

Or is there a recommended setup in how to achieve this>

Comment: What exactly do you want to inherit from `/blog/index`?

Comment: I have seen it before where a page simply uses another page but different getServerProps. It would just save me having two versions of the same page. I haven't actually tried to simply import it, but the way i have seen it used a different method (I dont have access to project I saw it in though to check setup).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use getServerSideProps method this is the only way to use in a next js project but If you don't need to use it on every single blog/[page].js
component , you can use queries with useEffect hook to update data with pagination on the page .

**Note**

If you use queries with useEffect hook to fetch data when paginating the getServerSideProps method will only run once in initial page load .